# How to get list items next to each other in stead of beneath each other using python/selenium

Tags: python, selenium

below is the code I'm using

```
with open ('Argentinie1Form.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as r:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/gdebr/Desktop/chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get("https://int.soccerway.com/national/argentina/primera-division/20182019/regular-season/r47779/")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    elm = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"""//*[@id="page_competition_1_block_competition_tables_7_1_4"]""")))
    elm.click()
    time.sleep(2)


with open ('Argentinie1Form.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as r:
    teams_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[contains(@id, 'page_competition_1_block_competition_tables_7_block_competition_form_table_1_table')]/tbody/tr/td[3]/a[1]")
    for items in teams_list:
        r.write(items.get_attribute('title')+'\n')
    MatchesPlayed_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[contains(@id, 'page_competition_1_block_competition_tables_7_block_competition_form_table_1_table')]/tbody/tr/td[4]")
    for matches in MatchesPlayed_list:
        r.write(matches.text+'\n')
```

The output I get is:

[image]

But in fact I want somethink like this:
Racing Club,5 and below this the next team and it's number

What am I dooing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

created one fucntion `concat_func` and defined 2 empty list, in which i am appending the data and then combine those list in to one

for example

```
a = ['x', 'z']
b = ['y', 'w']
concat_func = lambda x, y: str(x) + "," + str(y)     
# then
output = list(map(concat_func, a, b))
# output would be ['x,y', 'z,w']
```

**try this:**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/gdebr/Desktop/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://int.soccerway.com/national/argentina/primera-division/20182019/regular-season/r47779/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
elm = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"""//*[@id="page_competition_1_block_competition_tables_7_1_4"]""")))
elm.click()
time.sleep(2)

concat_func = lambda x, y: str(x) + "," + str(y)

with open ('Argentinie1Form.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as r:
    teams_list_append = []
    MatchesPlayed_list_append = []
    teams_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[contains(@id, 'page_competition_1_block_competition_tables_7_block_competition_form_table_1_table')]/tbody/tr/td[3]/a[1]")
    for items in teams_list:
        teams_list_append.append(items.get_attribute('title'))
        # r.write(items.get_attribute('title')+'\n')
    MatchesPlayed_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[contains(@id, 'page_competition_1_block_competition_tables_7_block_competition_form_table_1_table')]/tbody/tr/td[4]")
    for matches in MatchesPlayed_list:
        MatchesPlayed_list_append.append(matches.text)
        # r.write(matches.text+'\n')
    output = list(map(concat_func, teams_list_append, MatchesPlayed_list_append))

    for i in output:
        r.write(i + '\n')
```

Comment: I copied this and let it run but I got the same output.